# Logging properties using logback.xml on top of application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback

I have a 3rd party SpringBoot application with logs being configured in application.yml

```
logging:
    level:
        root: debug
        com:
            companyname: debug
```

We are trying to use logback.xml on top of it like so

```
logging:
    config: logback.xml
```

Logback.xml looks like this

```
<root level="debug">
<appender-ref../>
</root>
```

And it works normally, except the part that I don't see specifically com: companyname: DEBUG logs.
The question is how to configure log level for com: companyname: in logback.xml.

Tried this, but didn't work:

```
<logger name = "com.companyname" level = "DEBUG">
<appender-ref.../>
</logger>
```